# Firewall for VSTS Agent Configuration

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I set up firewall on my Agent, closed all TCP connections except for one server that I m using [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines) VSTS Task to deploy Websites to.

Powershell is failing on this line:

```
$environment = Register-Environment -EnvironmentName $environmentName -EnvironmentSpecification $environmentName -UserName $adminUserName -Password $adminPassword -WinRmProtocol $protocol -TestCertificate ($testCertificate -eq "true") -Connection $connection -TaskContext $distributedTaskContext -ResourceFilter $machineFilter
```

Without the firewall everything works fine.

What rule/port should I add to firewall to stop this error?

Comment: What's the message you get when the powershell was failing?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: An error occurred while sending the request.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT It takes around 1 minute to fail after timeout I guess

Comment: Can you run "winrm quickconfig" command first and then try it again?

Comment: This article include the way of trouble shooting, it may helps http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/understanding-and-troubleshooting-winrm-connection-and-authentication-a-thrill-seekers-guide-to-adventure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened port 443 as a Source Port to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable WinRM ports.

Run `Enable-PSRemoting –force` from an elevated PowerShell.

Comment: I m using an external firewall, and ports 5986 and 5985 are enabled. Without the external firewall everything works fine on Windows Firewall